how to manage volatile in a method which is marked @Async
In main service class i call another method which annotated with @Async.
In input params, i send volatile boolean value. If boolean true, @Async method working, if false, breaks from method.
From RestController anyTime i send request, to change volatile boolean value (for example false). If at this time payservice working, must be immediately finish work all threads and will be returned.

public class TestService {
    private volatile boolean isActive = false;
    private final PayService payservice;



    public void start() {
       for(int = 5; i < 99; i++) {
         payservice.pay(isActive);
       }
    }

}

public class PayService {

    @Async
    public void pay(boolean isActive) {

     for(int = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      if(isActive) {
       //toDo something
       }
     }
       
    }

}



You are passing the current value of the primitive boolean. PayService is not receiving a reference to TestService so it cannot see the field inside it. The value will never change. Java is pass-by-value.
